# FluentNHibernate mapping to a view

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, tableview

I have a many to many relationship between entities and there is a table view acting as a lookup table defining the relationship.

I'm curious how to map to a view as opposed to a table within a database.

ie, Table mapping:

```
public SomeMap()
{
    Id(...)//set Id and other mapped properties
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Items)
        .Table("SomeLookupTable")
        .ParentKeyColumn("ParentID")
        .ChildKeyColumn("ChildID")
        .LazyLoad()
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just stumbled across something in the FluentNHibernate Google Group area regarding this. In my test case I only use one self-referencing lookup, although in practice there is two. The issue is explained in detail [here.](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/4612913df1a4d916/9b07e19ce9e0de9e?lnk=gst&q=self-referencing#9b07e19ce9e0de9e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried mapping to the view as if it was a table? I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe just add .ReadOnly() and drop Cascase declaration, unless view is updatable

Comment: I have actually and this seems to work in a test case. My mapping is identical to what's above, however I'm presented with a "Can't figure out what the other side of a many-to-many should be." Strange, in the test case it does indeed map to the view with no issues.

Comment: Marked this as the answer due to the original question. Views are accessible just like tables, I had bumped into another issue entirely which was masking this(update above).